# Longest Palindromic Substring on Lintcode

Tags: python, index-error

I am a python starter and I am trying to solve the Longest Palindromic Substring problem on Lintcode. The description is:"Given a string S, find the longest palindromic substring in S. You may assume that the maximum length of S is 1000, and there exists one unique longest palindromic substring." I ran my codes, and it showed

> line 12, in ispalindrome while k[0] == k[-1]: IndexError: string index out of range.

I don't really know how could that error be raised. Can anyone help me review my codes.

```
def longestPalindrome(self, s):
    # write your code here
    if len(s) == 0 or len(s) == 1:
        return s
    else:
        def ispalindrome(k):
            while k[0] == k[-1]:
                k = k[1:-1]
            if len(k) > 1:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        for i in s:
            if s.rfind(i) > s.find(i):
                s = s[s.find(i):s.rfind(i)+1]
            if ispalindrome(s) == True:
                break
                return s
            else:
                s = s[1:-1]
```

Comment: `k` is an empty string. Empty strings have neither `k[0]` nor `k[-1]`. Change the condition to `while k and (k[0]==k[-1]):`.

Comment: I am little confused with "while k". What does that mean exactly?

Comment: It means "while k is not empty." You typically learn this before attempting to construct any `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
def longestPalindrome(s):
# write your code here
if len(s) == 0 or len(s) == 1:
    return s
else:
    def ispalindrome(k):
        while k and (k[0]==k[-1]):
            k = k[1:-1]
        if len(k) > 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    longestPalindromeLength=-1
    palindromeToReturn=None
    for i in s:
        if s.rfind(i) > s.find(i):
            subStr = s[s.find(i):s.rfind(i)+1]
            if ispalindrome(subStr) == True and longestPalindromeLength<len(subStr):
                    longestPalindromeLength=len(subStr)
                    palindromeToReturn=subStr
    return palindromeToReturn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, as for the input"aaabaaaa", this way won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution maybe you like it! but the code is not in python it's in js but you can use the logic

```
var temparry = []

    function Fsociety (){

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j <=input.length - i; j++) {

            //skipping empty strings

            if (input.substring(i, i + j) !== '') {
    
                if (input.substring(i, i + j) === input.substring(i, i + j).split("").reverse("").join("")) {
                    temparry.push(input.substring(i, i + j).length) 
    
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    }
    return temparry
    }

console.log(Math.max(...Fsociety(input)))// I'm telling math to give me the max value inside the temparry and here i'm passing function as a value
// console.log(Fsociety(input))
```

> <---- In the second if statement i'm telling js to check if it's a
> palindrome or not by first splitting it into single elements,then
> reversing it then i will simply join it as it's a string i will use
> === to tell js that check if they are equal or not are per the definition of palindrome if a word is equal to it's reverse then it's
> a palindrome  ---->